# Best approach to get products in order from database ??? based on product properties

Tags: elasticsearch, postgresql-9.1

I have to show products on my ecommerce website when user search query to My Elasticsearch
And having following features

- Order by user previous preference
- order by hot products

Comment: Elasticsearch or Postgres? The answer will be substantially different. Btw: Postgres 9.1 is no longer supported and shouldn't be used any more

Comment: Please at least give a sample document how it looks like, so it will be easier to discuss

Comment: what is previous preference? how do you know what a "hot product" is? Elasticsearch will not figure this out for you